Assembly is bloat: Hello-world in x86-64 (and C) contain oceans of null-bytes?
Sorry for the clickbait title.
TLDR
Running a simple Hello-world program in x86-64 assembly, which I'd guess should be maybe 100 Bytes, is actually 8KB. This is NOT explained by "the binary also uses extra libraries", because running the xxd hexdump program shows that the vast majority of the binary consists of 0-bytes. Seemingly totally wasted space. This page explains how to make the binary smaller, but I quite frankly don't get it.
In fact, the same holds for a hello world program in C, which is 16KB and also mostly 0-bytes.
Help me understand why this isn't crazy and why it happens.

Bloated Assembler Binary
Here is an x86-64 hello world assembly program which I got from here:
.global _start

.section .data
message: .ascii "Hello World\n"

.section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, offset message
    mov rdx, 12
    syscall
 
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

When I compile this with
$ as test.asm -o test.o
$ ld -s test.o -o test

It says that the test binary is 8KB(!!). On further inspection with xxd test, it turns out that the binary consists of thousands of zero bytes padding between what seems to be the code section and the data section. (to be honest, also seemingly lots of unnecessary zero bytes within these sections).
Here is the hexdump, and here is a small sample of it:
000000d0: 0f00 0000 0000 0000 0f00 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

Bloated C Binary
Here is a C hello world:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0; 
}

When I run this with gcc test.c -o test, it now gives me 16KB. Again running xxd test gives me the same pattern: an ocean of 0 bytes in between different sections, which themselves are filled with seemingly unnecessary 0 bytes.
Here is the hexdump, and here is a small sample of it:
000005f0: e83f 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0400 0000  .?..............
00000600: 0000 0000 0000 0000 f03f 0000 0000 0000  .........?......
00000610: 0600 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000620: f83f 0000 0000 0000 0600 0000 0600 0000  .?..............
00000630: 0000 0000 0000 0000 d03f 0000 0000 0000  .........?......
00000640: 0700 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000650: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000660: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000670: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000680: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000690: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000006a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000006b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000006c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000006d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

Why is this happening and how to fix it?
I guess this has something to do with ELF, but I don't know why. Surely there should be a way to get gcc to produce a binary of ~100 bytes for a program like this?

Why is it wasting such an obscene amount of space? I know it doesn't matter much for large programs, but still.

Is there a way to remove this wasted space in C automatically? E.g. to tell gcc to not include ELF somehow, would that fix it? (I'm not even sure why we'd need ELF if we're trying to compile/build a standalone program, and I didn't quite understand what is done here)



Due to paging and the fact that you have a .text and a .data with different flags you will need 2 pages of 4k each. You can use objcopy or directly linking into a binary if you don't want ELF (but then of course you won't be able to run the program under linux) Also apart from the memory page your storage device might also be using 4k blocks so the point is moot. As you said, for bigger program it amortizes anyway.

The executable file format has fixed sections that are present even if you don't use them. And the disk space is also allocated in chunks, so you save nothing by making the file smaller.

PS: somewhat ironic that you worry about size and then use unnecessarily large instructions :)

ELF isn't something you include. It's the executable file format. Trying to remove that is like trying to shorten a sentence by removing its English.

@Jester, Why do executables specifically need to have length equal to an integer amount of pages? other files don't have this restriction, right? If it's necessary to do this at the RAM level, then these paddings could just be removed from HDD and be included while loading the file from HDD?

It is the modern way because disk space is now so cheap and plentiful. I can recall various tools way back that would compress executables when a big hard disk was expensive and 10MB and floppies were 360kb each. Size of file is always at least one block so even if you squish it the disk allocation is 4k or a multiple the hardware uses.

You can try the -n or -N linker options.

Other files on disk also are allocated in sector sized units (which is at least 512 bytes but nowadays typically 4k) it's just that you don't see it. On linux you can use the du command, e.g. a single byte file on my system shows 4.0K byte.txt

@Jester, thanks guys, this clarifies it for me.

@MartinBrown: Some filesystems pack small files (or tails of files) together into the same 4k block to save disk space, or into the inode instead of a separate block to save space and avoid a level of indirection when accessing it later.  The now-obsolete ReiserFS did this, not sure about any modern FSes.  Maybe BTRFS for putting tiny files into their inode.

Looks like a duplicate of Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs? - it's padding to align ELF segments to 4K boundaries so they can be mapped into separate pages without any bytes in an executable page that don't need to be there, for security hardening.  You can indeed use a custom linker script and/or linker options to make a smaller executable.  Or hand-craft your own ELF using nasm -f bin with the machine code stuffed into don't-care fields inside the ELF header for a 45-byte _exit(42) program.

@PeterCordes UFS does that too.
